# Свечи (CandleStick) в ZedGraph

Tags: c#, winforms, zedgraph

Кто сможет объяснить как построить Свечи (Japanese Candle Stick Item) в библиотеке ZedGraph;

Будет две оси, одна t (Время), другая Y (значение какие то).
И относительно этих переменных мне надо построить график (свечи).

```
JapaneseCandleStickItem candle = pane.AddJapaneseCandleStick(name, требует IPointsList);
```

Как заполнить этот лист ? И можно ли окрашивать график ?

Comment: вряд-ли актуально, но что значит `окрашивать` график?

Answer (score 0):

[IPointList](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_IPointList.htm) это всего лишь интерфейс, на что собственно и намекает название. Его стандартная реализация в библиотеке `ZedGraph` это [PointPairList](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_PointPairList.htm).

`PointPairList` - это список пар для удобного представления точек - X,Y на плоскости или X,Y,Z в пространстве.

Пример:

```
        GraphPane pane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
        pane.CurveList.Clear();

        PointPairList l1 = new PointPairList();

        Random rand = new Random();
        int maxT = 30;
        int maxY = 30;
        foreach (var t in Enumerable.Range(0, maxT))
            l1.Add(t, rand.Next(maxY));

        pane.AddJapaneseCandleStick("Надпись", l1);
        zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
        zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
```